# p5.js mousePressed works but doublePressed doesnot?

Tags: p5.js

While programming my own minesweeper game, I have come to a stage(kind of final one) where I have to introduce the concept of Flags. Currently, I am using `mousePressed()` to open up any cell that might be a mine. But I cannot figure out a way how to flag any cell, as I tried to use `doubleClicked()` but it does not work in this case. Does anyone have any hint for this, or any built in `p5.js` tool that might simply flag a cell?

EDIT:

```
https://github.com/abj54/minesweeper
```

My code is in the above repo for anyone who might want to go through it. In terms of flag, it is a basic indicator of letting user guess which of the given cell may be a mine.

Comment: This question is liable to be **on hold** because you didn't provide any [MCVE] code, nor you clearly defined what is a "flag". As a result, it is not possible to answer this question adequately. The negative score only means that urgent attention is needed.

Comment: You'll have much better luck if you post a [mcve] directly in the post instead of providing a link to your entire codebase.

Answer (score 0):

Listening to booth events on the same object is problematic because of the event change which is called for a dblclick:

1. mousedown
2. mouseup
3. click
4. mousedown
5. mouseup
6. click
7. dbclick

P5.js checks the click/dblclick event of the window so you should not use both functions (click and dblclick). 
But you can use the click event with a Timeout to solve this problem.

```
var clicked=false, clickTimeout=300; 
function mouseClicked(){
  if(!clicked){
    clicked=true;
    setTimeout(function(){
      if(clicked){
        console.log("single click");
        clicked=false;
        //single ClickStuff

      }
    },clickTimeout);
  }else{
    clicked=false;
    console.log("double click");
    //double click Stuff
  }
}
```

So you are waiting the in clickTimeout defined amount of Time if a second click is called and react to.